# Creating Gist from a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, github, net-http, gist

Is there a way to create an Anonymous (public or private) gist using `net/http` or `net/https`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

uri = URI("https://api.github.com/gists")

payload = {
  'description' => "My test gist",
  'public' => true,
  'files' => {
    'test.txt' => {
      'content' => "This is a test!\n\nI am making a public gist."
    }
  }
}

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.body = payload.to_json

puts req.inspect
puts req.body.inspect

# GitHub API is strictly via HTTPS, so SSL is mandatory
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end

puts res.inspect
puts res.body.inspect
```

Result: [My test gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5513059)

Comment: Is there any way to do this call using Net::HTTP.post_form(...) ?

Answer (score 0):

This gem will do the trick for you https://github.com/defunkt/gist!

For the record, it does require net/https.

Comment: My issue is that I want just to add a little functionality in a gem of mine without adding a whole dependency.

Comment: http://www.travisberry.com/2011/05/create-github-gist-with-ruby/ - this should do the trick then.

Comment: This is a guide for Gtihub api v1